# Ubuntu terminal grep escape all the special characters in the search term literal

Tags: command-line, directory, search, source-code

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed in my system. Along with Magento CE 1.9.2.4 installed in webroot (`/var/www/html/`).

Now I want to `grep/egrep/fgrep` an entire line of code which may contain special chars like `$,<,>,',(,-,"` etc and what not.

How can I search the line of code like below in the whole Magento directory(in all files recursively) by escaping/allowing characters in the search term literal, with shortest syntax of grep line and quicker search ?

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(200)->keepFrame(false);
```

Can anyone help me out here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-F` option makes `grep` to interpret the pattern as a fixed string instead of a regex, and `-r` tells it to search recursively. But you still have to protect the `$` from the shell:

```
grep -F -r "\$this->helper('catalog/image')->init(\$product, 'image')->resize(200)->keepFrame(false);" /var/www/html/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer gives output as desired, one more thing, how can I include to look for mutliple file types in single `--include` parameter line ? Also are fileType groups(`application/php` for both `.php` and `.phtml`) allowed in `include` parameter ?

Comment: `--include` only accepts file globs, like `*.php` or `readme*`, not MIME types like `application/php`. You can use more than one `--include` to search for multiple globs, like `grep --include=\*.php --include=\*.phtml ...`